# Python: Scatter plot of data stored in matrix form

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a row vector showing x coordinates

```
x=[1,5,7,3]
```

and I have a matrix

```
y=[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,1,4],[1,2,2,1],[2,3,1,1]]
```

whose rows represent the scatter of a variable at the corresponding x coordinate.

I want to make a scatter plot of this, i.e. for each x, there are 4 different y values, which I want to plot. 
 Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip)

```
from itertools import cycle

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,5,7,3]
y = [[1,2,3,4], [2,3,1,4], [1,2,2,1], [2,3,1,1]]
for i in zip(x, y):
    b = zip(*(zip(cycle([i[0]]), i[1])))
    plt.scatter(*b)

plt.show()
```

Then your plot looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @User3100115

Fidgeting around I also found another solution, maybe not as efficient as @User3100115

```
x=[1,5,7,3]
y=[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,1,4],[1,2,2,1],[2,3,1,1]]

er=np.ones(4)
k=0
while k<4:
     e=x[k]*er
     plt.scatter(e,y[k])
     plt.draw()
     k+=1
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[1,5,7,3]
y=[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,1,4],[1,2,2,1],[2,3,1,1]]

for yy in y:
    plt.scatter(x,yy)

plt.show()
```

Comment: May be I wasn't clear, but each row contains the scatter, so for x=1 the scatter values are [1,2,3,4], for x=5 the scatter values are [2,3,1,4] and so on.